# every time I rerun my deep learning model it always gives a different loss result

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, tf.keras, random-seed

I'm studying a deep learning tutorial and I have the following simple data :

```
# Create feature
X = np.array([-7.0, -4.0, -1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0])

# Create labels
y = np.array([3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0, 24.0])

X = tf.cast(tf.constant(X), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.cast(tf.constant(y), dtype=tf.float32)
X,y
```

The output:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([-7., -4., -1.,  2.,  5.,  8., 11., 14.], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15., 18., 21., 24.], dtype=float32)>)
```

and from there, i build a simple deep learning regression model in Jupyter Notebook. Every time I rerun, I always get a different loss value :

```
# Set random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)

#1. Create a model using the sequantial API
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# 2. Compile the model
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae, # mae is short for mean absolute error
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), # sgd is short for stochastic gradient descent
              metrics=['mae'])

# 3. Fit the model
model.fit(tf.expand_dims(X, axis=-1),y, epochs=5)
```

Result :

```
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 272ms/step - loss: 21.7067 - mae: 21.7067
Epoch 2/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 21.3136 - mae: 21.3136
Epoch 3/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 20.9205 - mae: 20.9205
Epoch 4/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 20.5380 - mae: 20.5380
Epoch 5/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 20.2568 - mae: 20.2568
```

and everytime I rerun it again, it gives a different loss result, even though I've used a random seed in the hope that it will give the same result when I run it again:

```
Epoch 1/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 291ms/step - loss: 11.0655 - mae: 11.0655
Epoch 2/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 10.9330 - mae: 10.9330
Epoch 3/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 10.8005 - mae: 10.8005
Epoch 4/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 10.6680 - mae: 10.6680
Epoch 5/5
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 10.5355 - mae: 10.5355
```

how do i get the same loss result when i rerun the model in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Please add additional information as text, not images. They are a pain to read, and makes it harder to copy and paste from.

Comment: Try to Set it using `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(42)`.

Comment: @Frightera amazing, it works using ``tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(42)``. Thankyou very much !